# How to replace html symbols via sql query on php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a situation where I have a custom field with this html symbol (`&#8218;`). When I try to replace it by an equivalent (,) I just cannot do it...

I'm using this `sql` query:

```
$wpdb->query ("UPDATE $wpdb->postmeta SET `meta_value` = REPLACE(`meta_value`, \'%&#8218; %\') WHERE `meta_value` LIKE '‚'");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you mean to use `LIKE` like that? Will all `meta_key`s be `_description`, or did you maybe mean something like `%_description`?

Comment: the problem is that I have this on my custom field (&#8218;) and on sql, it get's converted to a comma automatically...

Answer (score 1):

To convert from &#8218; to a comma, use replace like below:

```
select replace(meta_value, '&#8218;', ',') from your_table where meta_value like ','
```

shown as select statement for testing, actual update:

```
update set your_table set meta_value = replace(meta_value, '&#8218;', ',') where meta_value like ','
```

Answer (score 1):

After search and trying, I manage to do this with this query:

```
$wpdb->query ("UPDATE $wpdb->postmeta set meta_value = replace(meta_value, '&#8218;', ',') WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'description'");
```